# Python Preventing Duplicates in User-Generated Integer List, While-loop and Try-Except

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, try-except

I want the user to input 10 unique integers in the set [1, 100]. This is my code so far:

```python
user_list = []
print "\nChoose any 10 discrete integers in the set [1, 100]. Do not choose duplicates."

i = 1

while i < 11:
    try:
        number_choice = int(raw_input("\nNumber %d?\n> " % i))

        if (0 <= number_choice <= 100) and isinstance(number_choice, int):
            i += 1
            user_list.append(number_choice)
            print "Your list so far: %r" % user_list
        elif (number_choice < 0) or (number_choice > 100):
            print "'I said to keep it in the set [1, 100].'"
            pass
        else:
            pass

    except ValueError:
        print "'That isn't a discrete integer, is it?'"

print sorted(user_list)
```

To prevent duplicates, I wanted to change the first `if` to read:

```python
if (0 <= number_choice <= 100) and (isinstance(number_choice, int)) and (number_choice not in user_list):
```

This would work, except it would just repeat the `"Number %d?" %  i` prompt again if the user input a duplicate. How can I modify this code so it first displays a prompt `'I said no duplicates.'` and then resumes the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the `i += 1` line:

```
if number_choice in user_list:
    print 'No duplicates!'
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for duplication first in the if statement, then check for valid integer and add it to the list in the "if else".